# wso2 esb twitter connector not invoking the twitter api

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 ESB Twitter connector operations in a proxy service. The proxy configuration as given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="twitter_test_proxy" transports="http https" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <twitter.init configKey="twitter_init"/>
            <twitter.getTopTrendPlaces configKey="twitter_init">
                <id>23424975</id>
            </twitter.getTopTrendPlaces>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

I imported the twitter connector to the esb and enable it. Then all the artifacts (proxy service and twitter_init local entry) were deployed in the ESB. Once I invoke the proxy service noticed that the twitter connector is not invoking the intended back end twitter API. I have enabled wire debug and the debug logs as per given below. What would be the reason for this? I'm using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1. I followed the instructions given [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Twitter+Connector#TwitterConnector-getTopTrends) in creating the configurations

```
[2014-11-12 20:07:47,785] DEBUG - header >> "POST /services/twitter_test_proxy.twitter_test_proxyHttpSoap12Endpoint HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2014-11-12 20:07:47,793] DEBUG - header >> "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8; action="urn:mediate"[\r][\n]"
[2014-11-12 20:07:47,793] DEBUG - header >> "Cookie: menuPanel=visible; menuPanelType=main; wso2.carbon.rememberme=admin-60c7726f-6e4b-462c-88c2-13753ab95974; JSESSIONID=6297A74817478FFE0F4B6EB392022E29; requestedURI="../../carbon/service-mgt/index.jsp?region=region1&item=services_list_menu"; region1_configure_menu=none; region3_registry_menu=none; region4_monitor_menu=none; region5_tools_menu=none; MSG14156327996440.7180992366157122=true; MSG14156330072650.6915075827877599=true; current-breadcrumb=manage_menu%2Cservices_menu%2Cservices_list_menu%23proxyservices+index.jsp*+index.jsp*; MSG14157205387400.9361328898335365=true; MSG14157205491900.33127844546453067=true; MSG14157205807580.7846254111223301=true; MSG14157216353420.11143615454004241=true[\r][\n]"
[2014-11-12 20:07:47,793] DEBUG - header >> "User-Agent: Axis2[\r][\n]"
[2014-11-12 20:07:47,793] DEBUG - header >> "Host: asanka-virtual-machine:8280[\r][\n]"
[2014-11-12 20:07:47,794] DEBUG - header >> "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
[2014-11-12 20:07:47,794] DEBUG - header >> "[\r][\n]"
[2014-11-12 20:07:47,794] DEBUG - content >> "a0[\r][\n]"
[2014-11-12 20:07:47,794] DEBUG - content >> "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"
[2014-11-12 20:07:47,795] DEBUG - content >> "[\r][\n]"
[2014-11-12 20:07:47,796] DEBUG - content >> "0"
[2014-11-12 20:07:47,796] DEBUG - content >> "[\r][\n]"
[2014-11-12 20:07:47,797] DEBUG - content >> "[\r][\n]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the above issue with slight modification to the proxy. I added respond mediator and got the expected result. The working proxy is as per given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="twitter-connector-proxy" transports="http https" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="INIT" value="##### Call to the Proxy #####"/>
            </log>
            <twitter.init/>
            <twitter.search configKey="twitter_init">
                <search>cricket</search>
            </twitter.search>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="RESULT" value="#### Twitter Search Result ####"/>
            </log>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```